# Подключиться к серверу в сети (PHP)

Tags: php, linux

Добрый день. Может быть вопрос покажется глупым или невозможным, но все-таки интересно.

Есть задача, в которой необходимо реализовать вывод картинок на странице в браузере. Когда картинки лежат в директории самого приложения (PHP) - тут все понятно, все работает. Но хотелось бы узнать, если картинки лежат на другом сервере, который находится в лок. сети с тем сервером, где само приложение, как я могу к ним обратиться?

Сервер, где стоит PHP на Линуксе, имеет адрес 192.168.101.7, а машина с картинками имеет адрес 192.168.101.7. С линукс сервера картинки доступны по лок. IP, а вот как в PHP к ним обратиться и вывести на страницу?

Comment: симлинком шару прикрутите да и все дела. доступ на чтение только выдайте

Comment: Картинки доступны в линуксе через лок айпи. Проблема только в том, как мне средствами php обратиться к этим картинкам и вытащить их оттуда.

Comment: дак в пхп-проекте сделайте symlink на папку с картинками на другом сервере, тогда и разницы не будет  на удаленной машине они или на самом сервере, и пхп вообще не при делах. возможно апачу там `followSymlinks` надо настроить будет для директории

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если сервер картинок доступен снаружи, просто указать правильный src для картинки.
А вот если сервер картинок снаружи НЕ доступен, то можно сделать скрипт, который будет читать картинки с другого сервера и отдавать их.

Comment: Да, оне не доступен снаружи, у него есть только локальный IP. Каким образом можно подключиться к нему и вытаскивать картинки оттуда? Я так понимаю, что скрипт нужен, который будет обращаться к серверу по лок. сети по его IP, вытаскивать нужную картинку, класть ее у себя в папке где-то и уже из этой папке по src выводить?

Comment: Не совсем. Я бы сделал скрипт, например img.php, урл которого подставляется в src с параметром указывающем на картинку. Например, /img.php?get=filename_to_get.jpg  . А уже при запросе картинки браузером будет вызван скрипт img.php и он скачает и сразу отдаст картинку.

Comment: С этим проблем нет, я понял. Не могу только разобраться, как с сервера, на котором PHP обратиться к компьютеру, на котором лежат картинки по лок. IP?

Comment: Иван, могли бы подсказать, какими средствами можно вытащить картинку с сервера в локальной сети и отдать на веб-страницу?

Comment: Самый простой способ - подключить в качестве сетевого диска папку с удаленного сервера. Другие альтернативы - ftp, ssh, будут не настолько удобны. Также можно поднять на другом сервере веб-сервер, и настроить его на отдачу картинок.